# tomcat stand alone application inside web application

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp, vaadin

I have web application made with vaadin framework. I have another, separate java application that listens to some port and using TCP/IP communication accepts soe datza from some clients. That application now starts with system, just like tomcat. I was wondering is it possible to put that stand alone application inside this web app, but it need to starts along with tomcat? Idea is to have inside one application both functionality - for users web application and for accepting data (data comes from devices over TCP/IP and application parse it and write record to database) this another application, so they can easy communicate with each other - I need data that comes to port to be recorded into data base and also sent to web applicatio for further calculation...

Comment: Write a servlet and start the application in the init method and configure the servlet to load on startup.

Comment: thanks :) i was searching meanwhile and got same conclusion...

Comment: Post your solution as answer please.